# Why is array_rand() working with two elements but not more, or less than that?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm randomly trying to select a text string from an array. I have a single dimension array with the same kind of structure as the following:

```
$jokes = array("Why is Peter Pan always flying? He neverlands." ,
                "My girlfriend yelled at me today saying, \"You weren't even listening just now, were you?! I thought, \"Man, what a weird way to start a conversation.\"", 
                "I used to have a job collecting leaves. I was raking it in.",
                "What's the leading cause of dry skin? Towels.",
                "I tell you what often gets overlooked - garden fences.",
                "I wear a stethoscope so that in a medical emergency I can teach people a valuable lesson about assumptions.",
                "Toasters were the first form of pop-up notifications.",
                "I love sniffing my F1 key... don't worry though, I'm trying to get help.",
                "I just ate a frozen apple. Hardcore.",
                "RIP boiled water. You will be mist.",
                "Archaeology really is a career in ruins...",
                "You know what they say about cliffhangers...",
                "I went out with a girl called Simile, I don't know what I metaphor.",
                "My server sings, it's a Dell.");
```

And I'm selecting items from it using:

```
echo json_encode($jokes[array_rand($jokes, count($jokes)-1)]);
```

If I only have two items in the array then it randomizes perfectly however as soon as I go over or under  that number nothing returns.

Comment: I don't think `array_rand` works the way you think it should. Have you read the [docs](http://php.net/array_rand)?

Comment: From the documentation of [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php): When picking only one entry, `array_rand()` returns the key for a random entry. Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is returned. In the second case `$jokes[array_rand(...)]` is the same as `$jokes['Array']` and it is, obviously, not set.

Comment: Better use `shuffle()` like `shuffle($jokes); $jokes=array_values($jokes);/*re-index*/ print $jokes[0];`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: those jokes are terrible

Comment: @Codingo Check my post hope it will work fine for you, I dont know why downvote.

Comment: @SahilGulati Downvote wasn't from me!

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix Sure, but I'm not putting production data on S/O now am I..

Comment: @Codingo Okay not issue, But what wrong with my post Do i misunderstood your question.

Comment: What is happen here downvotes for an correct answer form @SahilGulati, now it is removed. Its an simple task ?!??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't jam an array of keys (square peg) into a parameter expected to be an index (round hole).

```
var_export(array_rand($jokes,count($jokes)-1));
```

Will output something like:

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 2,
  3 => 3,
  4 => 4,
  5 => 6,
  6 => 7,
  7 => 8,
  8 => 9,
  9 => 10,
  10 => 11,
  11 => 12,
  12 => 13,
)
```

What you can do is:

```
$rand_keys=array_rand($jokes,sizeof($jokes)-1);
var_export($rand_keys);
$rand_jokes=array_intersect_key($jokes,array_flip($rand_keys));
echo "\n",json_encode($rand_jokes);
```

This will output (notice the preserved keys):

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 2,
  3 => 3,
  4 => 4,
  5 => 5,
  6 => 6,
  7 => 8,
  8 => 9,
  9 => 10,
  10 => 11,
  11 => 12,
  12 => 13,
)
{"0":"Why is Peter Pan always flying? He neverlands.","1":"My girlfriend yelled at me today saying, \"You weren't even listening just now, were you?! I thought, \"Man, what a weird way to start a conversation.\"","2":"I used to have a job collecting leaves. I was raking it in.","3":"What's the leading cause of dry skin? Towels.","4":"I tell you what often gets overlooked - garden fences.","5":"I wear a stethoscope so that in a medical emergency I can teach people a valuable lesson about assumptions.","6":"Toasters were the first form of pop-up notifications.","8":"I just ate a frozen apple. Hardcore.","9":"RIP boiled water. You will be mist.","10":"Archaeology really is a career in ruins...","11":"You know what they say about cliffhangers...","12":"I went out with a girl called Simile, I don't know what I metaphor.","13":"My server sings, it's a Dell."}
```

If you don't need to preserve the keys, you can use `shuffle()` then collect the full array, bar the last one.

```
shuffle($jokes);
array_pop($jokes);
echo json_encode($jokes);
```

Outputs something like:

```
["What's the leading cause of dry skin? Towels.","Archaeology really is a career in ruins...","Why is Peter Pan always flying? He neverlands.","I tell you what often gets overlooked - garden fences.","Toasters were the first form of pop-up notifications.","I wear a stethoscope so that in a medical emergency I can teach people a valuable lesson about assumptions.","My girlfriend yelled at me today saying, \"You weren't even listening just now, were you?! I thought, \"Man, what a weird way to start a conversation.\"","My server sings, it's a Dell.","I love sniffing my F1 key... don't worry though, I'm trying to get help.","I used to have a job collecting leaves. I was raking it in.","RIP boiled water. You will be mist.","I just ate a frozen apple. Hardcore.","You know what they say about cliffhangers..."]
```

**Late Edit:  I failed to acknowledge your use case.**

If you just want to output a single random joke use:

```
echo $jokes[array_rand($jokes)];
```

By not specifying the second/optional parameter of `array_rand()` it will return a single key.  Otherwise, if you ask it to return more than one key, it will return an array of keys.  Your second parameter `count()-1` works on a 2-element array, because you are only asking for 1 key in return (2 - 1); when handling a larger `$jokes` array you will have problems with your original method.